# An idiom meaning "doing something different" this time around?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom or phrase or slang that I can use in order to say:

> This time around, I will do something a little bit different.
>
> This time around, I will do something completely different from last
>   time.

Comment: Could you provide more context?  Are you talking about a small task or a really big endeavor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a more general sense, I would suggest **branch out**.

> to start doing something different from the work or activities that you normally do ([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/branch_2))

It is also possible to say **branch out into something** or **branch out into doing something**.

> Example 1: Don’t be afraid **to branch out when choosing your cuisine**.
>
> Example 2: The company **branched out into selling clothes**.

In addition, in the context of traveling to some new place, **going off the beaten path** or **off the beaten track** might work, I think.

This idiom refers to a place not known or popular by many, so it may imply novelty in context, as in:

> We always stay at the same hotel every year. This summer let's go off the beaten path. (I. e. let's do things differently.)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatives for this:

> To change over
>  Try something new
>  Strike out
>  Change
>   direction/course

[Reference](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-start-doing-something-new-or-different)

Also, see [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/strike+out.html) for an example how to use **strike out** in this context.

Comment: how does strike out work in the above context that the OP has asked?

Comment: @MamtaD http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strike-out

Comment: Please rephrase "This time around, I will do something completely different from last time" using "strike out".

Comment: @MamtaD in this context "This time I will strike out" or "It's time to strike out"

Comment: That's **incorrect** actually in this context. *strike out* in your sentence means **cross out** or **eliminate**.

Comment: @MamtaD No..it doesn't mean eliminate, it means try something new.

Comment: "try something new" is for "strike out on one's own" but you haven't included that in your sentence. Yours stops at **out**.

Comment: @MamtaD its quite similar to this- http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/strike+out.html

Comment: Ok! That's good then.

Answer (score 1):

**Change tack**

> A method of dealing with a situation or problem; a course of action or
>   policy

In simple words, it means change direction, do something different than before.

**References**:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tack

http://grammarist.com/usage/tack-tack/

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/change+tack

Answer (score 1):

**Shift (or *switch*) gears**

> shift gears: to change what you are doing in a sudden way:
>   *I'd like to shift gears and start a new job.*

[**My English Pages**](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/random-idiom.php?c=460)

Answer (score 1):

You could *[ring the changes](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ring+the+changes)*:-

> to make something more interesting by changing it in some way [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary]

so your sentence would read...

> This time around, I will *ring the changes*.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to try to change (and hopefully improve upon) **the outcome** (and not just the process) of something you've tried before, you can “[shake/mix things up **a bit/a little**](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6cVfxS-8qsC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22shake+things+up+a+bit%22+%22try+something+different%22&source=bl&ots=c-_tiL0m2C&sig=BznHmU_OsCNrjthwBibHuR_W3h8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBWoVChMIv_bkhtfEyAIVSfceCh0FCAJT#v=onepage&q=%22shake%20things%20up%20a%20bit%22%20%22try%20something%20different%22&f=false)” to try to achieve something slightly different (example from ‘Arrows of Light: Devotions for Worldwide Christians’/Google Books).
Or to go all the way you can simply omit “a bit/a little” and really “[shake/mix things up](http://man.bodyandsoul.com.au/sex+dating/sex+tips/4+ways+to+shake+things+up+in+the+bedroom,24911)” (example from Body & Soul, Man).

[Shake something up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shake-sth-up): “to cause large changes in something such as an organization, usually in order to make improvements” (from Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

Answer (score 0):

the idiom or proverb I would suggest for  divergent thinkers or voices of different opinions is- a flamingo in a pack of piegons or a blue rose in a white bouquet, or the thinker of a different shade .descriptions of such ppl can be made as the out of the box thinkers

> the different dont think outside the box ,they think that there is no box
>   if everyone is alike no one is thinking
>   our eyes are are useless if the mind is blind                        -mannat
>   hope this was helpful.....